# resource linux script, disable/flush extra input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Good afternoon everyone,

I have created a resource monitoring tool that works fairly well.

- Pulls CPU average usage
- Pulls average Memory usage
- Even calculates % of NIC throughput (if you have a 1Gb NIC, it'll show percent that is being processed at a time)... and yes I know this is more of a rough estimate/theoretical max limit of a NIC.

I am having one issue with my script though. Portion of the code I am experiencing my issue with is below (I converted some to pseudo code for simplicity).

```
COUNT=1
read -rsp "When you are ready to begin, please press any key" -n1
echo "processing"
sleep 3
while [ ${COUNT} = "1" ; do
  read -t 1 -n 1
  if [$? = 0 ] ; then
    exit 0
  else
 `Resource command` > ${cpulog} file for future graphs
 `Resource command` > ${memlog} file for future graphs
 `Resource command` > ${network} log file for future graphs
 `etc`
 fi
done
```

Basically, you hit any key to start the program, and whenever you press any key on the keyboard after the program has started (While loop), the program stops recording information and moves on.

Now this script works and does everything I need it to do. The issue I have come across is when you **"press any key"**.

Note that there are two points in the script waiting for a key press.

If I were to press any **key** more than once at the first point, the second key input would get processed by my `read -t 1 -n 1` command (at the second point), and thus fail to run my resource pulls.  Since that happens immediately, the script fails.

Basically, I am trying to figure out if there is a way I can shutdown input after that first key stroke for a limited time while I retrieve a limited amount of data, or flush any input that was given prior to hitting my `read -t 1` command. Thank you.

Comment: you need to input only one character?

Comment: In order to stop pulling resource information, you would hit any key to stop the program.

Comment: In order to start the program, you have to hit any key as well. Problem is if you start the program by accidently hitting more than one key, the additional key stroke is sent to my `read -t 1` portion and causes program to fail.

Comment: To answer your question...I would like to have this program start and stop by pressing any single key/character. Not a necessity but a want. If I cannot accomplish it this way, I will accept that to.

Comment: I get what you mean, but my question is your script launched without pressing enter key ?

Comment: It waits for input on the `read -rsp` line. As soon as you press any key, the script continues and begins the `while loop`.  Perhaps I am not understanding your question completely.

Comment: I understood wait I have an idea I ll try on my system if it works i ll post it

Comment: Why not have the user press "CTRL-C" to stop the script?

Comment: Also note that, as currently presented, the script has several syntax errors.

Comment: I do not want to stop the script when a key is pressed, I just want the script to proceed past the resource collection phase which is why I do not use CTRL-C. Sorry about the syntax errors, I tried to just put up enough code/pseudo code so everyone could see my issues/help explain. Actual script is WAY different

Comment: I didn't -1 that answer but introducing extra delays isn't a general solution to throwing away stdin, after a "hit any key to continue".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the "processing line," add the following loop:

```
# Eat any remaining input
while read -t 1 -n 1
do
   # Do nothing here
   :
done

# Continue processing now that all input has been consumed...
```

It will add about 1 second delay to startup (more if the user is sitting there pressing keys), but otherwise does what you want.

Comment: darn those -1's without comment... Wish I understood why this answer deserves a -1 here.

Comment: the code doesn't work, it is still accepting the second value

Comment: odd, I tested it myself.  This code eats the input there at the time it's run, but won't eat any input after that... could there be more going on?

Comment: read -rsp "When you are ready to begin, please press any key" -n 1
printf "\n processing"
while read -t 1 -n 1 
do
        echo "passed";
sleep 1; 
done

Comment: ah, I think you misunderstood the ':' - that's a literal colon, not the rest of your code.

Comment: Are you saying to modify my `"Ready to begin please press a key"` portion, and throw that into a while loop itself?

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I got it know I will +1 you on another post as this vote here is locked

Comment: +2 I hope that was fear enough

Comment: Ignore my comments haha, took me a second to understand what you are doing with that code. what is the colon doing if I might ask? This worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: The colon is a "noop".  Unfortunately, you must have a statement between the "do" and "done", so the colon comes to the rescue.  Note that it can get a little more complicated than that if you do more on the same line as the colon.  `man bash` should explain it if you're up for a long read.

Comment: : is NOT really a "noop", it's a bash builtin which evaluates to true useful for things like "while :  # loop forever", the Bourne shell would fork & execute /bin/true

Answer (score 2):

The script can call a small program, written in C, perl or similar, which calls the FIONREAD ioctl on stdin.

Then read the unexpected extra characters to be thrown away with a read call, see  [Perl Cookbook to determine unread bytes](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/library/slaconly/cdbook/perl/cook/ch07_22.htm)
You can actually enter the perl code on command line with perl -e. to keep it all within the bash script.